# Getting an error when trying to create a persistent volume

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to create a persistent volume on my kubernetes cluster running on an Amazon AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu 18.04).  I'm getting an error from kubectl when trying to create it.

I've tried looking up the error but I'm not getting any satisfactory search results.

Here is the pv.yaml file that I'm using.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv001
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
    storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  hostPath:
    path: /home/ubuntu/data/pv001
```

Here's the error that I am getting:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "./mysql-pv.yaml": 

PersistentVolume in version "v1" cannot be handled as a 
PersistentVolume: v1.PersistentVolume.Spec: 
v1.PersistentVolumeSpec.PersistentVolumeSource: HostPath: Capacity: 
unmarshalerDecoder: quantities must match the regular expression 
'^([+-]?[0-9.]+)([eEinumkKMGTP]*[-+]?[0-9]*)$', error found in #10 byte
of ...|":"manual"},"hostPat|..., bigger context ...|city":
{"storage":"1Gi","storageClassName":"manual"},"hostPath":
{"path":"/home/ubuntu/data/pv001"},"p|...
```

I cannot figure out from the message what the actual error is.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi, ignore this request.  I've solved the problem.  I believe that it was that I didn't have quotes around the path name as well as not putting the API Version directive first.

Comment: I had this same issue when using MiB instead of Mi as unit for storage parameter..

Answer (score 3):

remove the storage class from pv definition. storage class is needed for dynamic provisioning of pv's.

in your case, you are using host path volumes. it should work without storage class.

If you are on k8s 1.14 then look at local volumes. refer the below link
https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/13/local-persistent-volumes-beta/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's related to having quotes in the `path`. It's more about using the right indentation for `storageClassName` (yours had one tab too many, moving it under `capacity`). It should be this instead:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv001
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  hostPath:
    path: /home/ubuntu/data/pv001
```

You can remove it too, and it will use the default `StorageClass`.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by changing the mi to Mi with a capital case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv001
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  storageClassName: manual
 accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
 persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
 hostPath:
   path: /home/ubuntu/data/pv001
```

`storageClassName` is under `spec` and same level as `capacity` (You put `storageClassName` under `capacity` which is wrong).
Read more: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/